# Xcode 6 : Using external reSIProcate dylib, trowing “class member cannot be redeclared” upon building

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, llvm

I'm pretty new to Cocoa/Xcode. I'm more of web developmer who finally wants to make great Mac OSX.

I managed to build reSIProcate library, not without troubles. I also managed to link this group of .dylib and their header files. Ok. Not forgotten to use it in Ocjective-C++ files (renamed my `.m` to `.mm`).
Fine.
What? `unknown type name 'Int32' & 'Int16'`?
Found that I had to create a Prefix Header file to globally declare those basic types:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef signed int Int16;
typedef signed int Int32;
typedef uint16_t UInt16;
typedef uint32_t UInt32;
```

Ok, that's done. That problem’s solved. Now what…

I now get error: `class member cannot be redeclared` in :

```
'[…]/include/rutil/resipfaststreams.hxx:139:25'
ResipFastOStream& operator<<(Int32 l)
                  ^
```

Well, now I'm stuck. Is there a way to tell LLVM compiler to step over this fatal error?
How can this append under Xcode, but apparently no one else complained about it?

How can I solve this?

Any thoughs are welcome.

Comment: I suspect you also have a ResipFastOStream& operator<<(Int16 l)? If that's the case, that's likely to be your problem. TBH, aliasing both Int16 and Int32 to plain int doesn't make that much sense to me compared to the way you deal with the uints...

Comment: Yes you're right, I also get this error. I understand what's the problem. But if I change `typedef signed int Int16;` to `typedef uint16_t Int16;` (and 32s…) it doesn't really help, I now have twice the errors thrown. What could I have done to solve my initial problem in the first place?

Comment: How about this?
typedef short Int16;
typedef int Int32;
typedef uint16_t UInt16;
typedef uint32_t UInt32;